# gwt tablayout hides the tabs when increasing padding, font, margin

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, gwtp, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I have created the `TabLayoutPanel`. If its

`.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner`

CSS Class is modified with padding, say 
`padding: 15px;` or `font-size: 25px;`

then, the tabs hide with in the browser window. What is the reason and how to fix this?

Thanks,
Bennet.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess (without seeing any code) but I bet you haven't added your TabLayoutPanel properly.  The "Layout" panels are great but you you have to play by the rules.

Make sure that you have an unbroken link of "layout" type panels all the way down to the "RootLayoutPanel".

Also, verify that you are in fact using the "RootLayoutPanel" and NOT the "RootPanel" to add your gwt widget to the dom

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(myTabLayoutPanel);
```

See here, specifically the section titled "RequiresResize" and "ProvidesResize"
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels

Comment: I am using uibinders, How do I add the layout panel in uibinder with this rule??

Answer (score 0):

`.gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner` is the wrapper around the `label` displayed in the actual `tab`. When you try to increase the `padding` (say `padding : 'z'px;`)what happens is it pushes the label by 'z' pixels from all sides and it eventually hides behind the enclosing div or the `.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs`. 
As a solution you can either adjust the `padding` so that it doesn't hide behind the parent `div` or increase the `size` of parent so as to allow the `tabs` take more `padding`.

Comment: What you said is good idea. I fixed it by increasing the bar height.  I am sorry, in this I couldn't understand "increase the size of parent", what is this mean? I am using uibinders with gwtp, how do I add this layout panel to rootlayout panel. please help me foe this.

Comment: Increase enclosing parent height is something I should have said I guess..I am not that familiar with gwtp I will investigate more but you can always enclose your ui binder in a layout panel instead of the default htmlpanel and then add to root layout panel as suggested in the other answer